# Product name is undefined after building electron app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

After building my Electron application, it displays a product name of `undefined`. How can I set any other name instead?

This is how it currently looks:

[image: preview image]

Comment: post your `package.json` – that's where the app name is defined (afaik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this it will work. Refer this link
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item

```html
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
 {
 label: 'elctron',
 role: 'appMenu'
 },
 {
 label: 'Edit',
 role: 'editMenu'
 }
 ])
```